# FFC Connector Identification

Tags: connector, identification, ffc

I need to design an FPC to couple to an existing board. There are 3 FFC connections on this board. I believe them all to be Molex connectors but I still can't locate a similar part. Here is what I know:

1. The locking tab labeled 'A3' on one end and 'KK1' on the other. The pitch is .5mm. There are 17 positions and they face up when inserted into the connector. There are tabs on each side of the FFC measuring .05" in width and .07" in length. The thickness of the stiffener is roughly .012".
2. The locking tab labeled 'A5' on one end and 'MXJ' on the other. The pitch is .3mm. There are 31 positions and they face down when inserted into the connector.There are no ears/tabs on the mating FFC. The thickness of the stiffener is roughly .009"
3. The locking tab labeled 'A7' on one end and 'MXJ' on the other. The pitch is .3mm. There are 21 positions and they face down when inserted into the connector. The thickness of the stiffener is roughly .006".

Unfortunately I don't have access to anything more than a camera phone at the moment so I don't have any quality pictures to provide. I am hoping the information above is enough for someone familiar with these parts, but I will add images as soon as possible.

I have located several Molex FFC connectors that look similar but nothing that looks identical. I am not sure that it REALLY matters that I find the same exact part as it's not the connector I am after but the recommended FFC layout and stiffener size.

Suggestions?

Comment: need to know FPC thickness, just a heads up metric is the way to go on specs.. most of the good ones are Hirose.

Comment: OK next Board height (SMT) and FPC taper/straight//notched?

Comment: I'll pull the connector dimensions... the FFCs are either tabbed or straight as noted in the question.

Comment: not the FFC , the FPC.. it can be tapered straight or key notched

Answer (score 2):

EDIT #2  ( found item #2 non-stock from HIROSE ) 
I used to distribute alternate connectors in volume by matched parts from my company factory direct in few weeks. MOQ 500$

"your friendly component engineer says"

You may consider;

1. 17p 0.5mm pitch 0.3mm th. up & ears, straight =====>MOLEX 0545501771
2. 32p 0.3mm pitch 0.2mm th. down & no ears ==> HIROSE FH26-21S-0.3SHW(?)  many options (?) different MOQ 300~3000  http://www.hirose.co.jp/cataloge_hp/e58302093.pdf
3. 21p 0.3mm pitch 0.15mm th. down, no ears,straight ====> JAE FB6S021JA1 
   http://jae-connector.com/en/pdf/SJ102078.pdf

FFC Sources: AVX, FCI, MOLEX, Harwin, HIROSE,JAE JST, OMRON, PANASONIC, SAMTEC, TE, WURTH

---

extraneous info as follows for  those who want to see FPC specs.

http://ca.mouser.com/hiroseFFCFPC/  match FPC thickness and pitch to desired 0deg connector .
[image]

Comment: This is a Hirose part. Will it matter with respect to the FFC layout? Are they consistent across manufacturers? That's all I really care about.

Comment: When you specify all the physical parameters that affect plug compatibility at one end, the connector at the other end wont matter. Nor will board height. Locking mechanism is personal choice but pitch, thick, # positions and taper do matter. top/bot is personal choice as is 0/90deg.